# get the scheduling data based on 3 years in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table bibles that having two columns only i.e. is below:-

```
id   chapter_name 
1      Mathews 1
2      Mathews 2
3      Mathews 3
4      Mathews 4
...    ....
...    ....
364    Revelation 22  //Total Records only 364 fixed. that will not increase
```

Bible Scheduling starts from **5 sept 2021** for 3 years and ends on **31 Aug 2024** i.e basically  bible repeats three time in 3 years.

Now Suppose today date is 8 Sept 2021

```
 id   chapter_name     date_1             date_2          date_3 
 1      Mathews 1     2021-09-05        2022-09-04        2023-09-03
 2      Mathews 2     2021-09-06        2022-09-05        2023-09-04        
 3      Mathews 3     2021-09-07        2022-09-06        2023-09-05  
 4      Mathews 4     2021-09-08        2022-09-07        2023-09-06
...    ....
...    ....
```

So now requested date is **8 spet 2021** i want to fetch the 4th record **Mathews 4** and now suppose today date is **6 sept 2022** and now want to fetch the 3 row **Mathews 3**.

Note : these date columns are not stored in database. i have only two columns  id, chapter_name.. Reason for not storing the dates because after three years i need to update again that dates to make scheduling works. Is there any way to fetch the rows?

Below answer works fine but I have two types of Bibles that starts from Id 1 to 364 another starts from 365 to 1456... 1st case
1 to 364 works.. but 365 to 1456 not works

Comment: How do you know which date corresponds with which chapter ?

Comment: from 1st to 364 chapters are added in such way that date not vary, chapter1 for row 1 ,, chapter2 for row 2

Comment: chapter 1 fwill be read 5 sept, chapter 2 will be readon 6  sept

Comment: Well you can convert the dates to unix timestamps and find number of days between a start date and the date for which the record is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then logic you want is:

```
where dateadiff(?, '2021-09-05') % 364 = id - 1
```

The `?` is a parameter for the date you pass in.

Comment: It's not works when my id starts from 365 to 1456 I have another type of bible that starts from 365

Comment: @kunal . . . That is not the question that you asked here.  If you have a different question, then ask it as a *new* question.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with some anchor date in the past, `2020-09-06` will do.

The `id` in your table is a number of days between the anchor date and the current date mod 364 (the number of rows in your table).

```
SELECT
    id, chapter_name
FROM bibles
WHERE
    id = DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), '2020-09-06') % 364 + 1
;
```

The `DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), '2020-09-06')` function returns the number of days between the current date and the anchor date `2020-09-06`, i.e. the number of days between the date when the schedule started and now. This number can grow larger than 364 (the number of rows in your table). To "wrap" this number back to 0 when it is larger than 364 we use the modulo division (mod) or `%` operator. And then add 1, because ids in your table start with 1 (if they started with 0 you didn't have to add 1).

Try to run this query replacing the `CURRENT_DATE()` with your sample dates `2021-09-08` and `2022-09-06`.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2021-09-08', '2020-09-06') % 364 + 1;
```

returns 4 (4th row)

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2022-09-06', '2020-09-06') % 364 + 1;
```

returns 3 (3rd row)

---

It means that if you run the full query with the `CURRENT_DATE()` function on `2021-09-08` it will return a row with id=4. When you run the query on `2022-09-06` it will return a row with id=3.

Comment: where you define the scheduling start date 5 sept ?

Comment: @kunal, the start of the scheduling is defined by the constant `2020-09-06` in the query. It is 5 sept 2021 minus 364 days. I chose the date that is in the past to make sure that `DATEDIFF` returns positive number.

Comment: @kunal, in other words, imagine you had your schedule already started in 2020, then it had to start on `2020-09-06` to get back to the first chapter on 5 sept 2021. You can extend the schedule into the future and into the past indefinitely.

Comment: what does that 364 that static value?

Comment: 364 is the number of rows in your table. after each 364 days you re-start the schedule, hence we calculate `mod 364`.

Comment: can you tell what exactly this works DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE(), '2020-09-06') % 364 + 1 ?

Comment: @kunal, I added explanation of the formula to the answer

Comment: what if my id starts from 365 ?

Comment: i have one more query can you help?

Comment: if i want to fetch 3 rows on same date suppose reading schedule on sept 5 is chapter1, chapter 2, chapter 3 for 1 year

Comment: It's not works when my id starts from 365 to 1456 I have another type of bible that starts from 365 @vladimir

Comment: Sorry @kunal, I can't explain the formula more clearly than I already did. Once you understand how it works for the situation described in the question you should be able to adapt it to a different situation.

Comment: Please help me i need it urgent please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229040/discussion-between-kunal-and-vladimir-baranov).

Comment: 365 to 1456 data not came any suggestions?